# При firebase deploy HTTP Error: 400. Billing account for project ... is not found

Tags: reactjs, firebase, frontend

При первой попытке отправить запрос, у меня появляется такое сообщение.
Error: HTTP Error: 400, Billing account for project '-----------' is not found. Billing must
be enabled for activation of service(s) 'cloudbuild.googleapis.com,containerregistry.googleapis.com' to proceed.
Как я понял теперь нужно вводить карточку, что я и сделал, а вот что дальше активировать непойму. В Фаербейсе теперь данный из гугл кабинета брать? Какие точно подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0):

Простите господа, запутался. Если комунибудь нужно подобное решение - оно просто. Все дело в оплате самого плана на firebase. Теперь Нужно брать повышенный план - он по сути бесслатный как был так и остался. Правда если вы пользуетесь активно - вы платите за трафик. Только что оплатил аккаунт и запрос отправился.